# Can I stop Windows displaying a folder as 'My Pictures' when its physical path is different?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-home-server

I have a folder on my Windows Home Server where I store my RAW photos. The path on the server is `E:\ServerFolders\Photography`, and is shared at `\\server\Photography`. However, at some time since initially setting it up, Windows Explorer has decided that this should be the `My Pictures` folder for the server (or user, however it works it out), and consequently Windows Explorer displays the folder as `My Pictures` instead of `Photography`.

Is there any way to change this behaviour? Firstly, there is also a `Pictures` directly which would more accurately meet the `My Pictures` idiom, but more to the point, as it's only a server and everything is accessed via shares, when remoting in I'd rather see the file system in explorer exactly as it is. `dir` from the command prompt correctly lists the folder as `Photography`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `E:\ServerFolders\Photography\Desktop.ini`. From the `[.ShellClassInfo]` section, delete all lines starting with `LocalizedResourceName=`. (Or just delete the file entirely.)

Answer (score 1):

Like @@grawity said but make sure to enable hidden files.

Open the your folder in normal explore. Click on "Tools" (if its not there press alt and a menu will drop down) > "Folder Options"  > "Views" > Hidden files and folders > Show Hidden Files and folders.

If there is not desktop.ini then its in the registry and you have to

Right click on the folder > "Properties" > "Customize" - And change the template or customise it to your likes.